# pandas merge with condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, merge

I have two dataframe and want to merge it based on max of another column

```
df1:
C2
A
B
C

df2:
C1 C2 val
X  A  100
Y  A  50.5
Z  A  60
E  B  90
F  B  45
G  C  100
```

I tried,

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='C2', how='inner')['val'].max()
```

I get the error, `AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'head'`

The val column has only numbers. How should I modify this and Why do I encounter this error ?

The expected output is:

```
df3:
C2 C1 val
A  X  100
B  E  90
C  G  100
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by left join:

```
df3 = df2.merge(df1, on='C2', how='left')
```

And then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices of max values per groups and select rows by `loc`:

```
df3 = df3.loc[df3.groupby('C2')['val'].idxmax()]
```

Or use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df3 = df3.sort_values(['C2', 'val']).drop_duplicates('C2', keep='last')
print (df3)
  C1 C2    val
0  X  A  100.0
3  E  B   90.0
5  G  C  100.0
```

> Why do I encounter this error ?

Problem is you get scalar - max value of column `val`:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='C2', how='inner')['val'].max()
print (df3)
100.0
```

So if use `print (df3.head())` it failed.